# How to repair this problematic hard drive?

Tags: fsck, corruption

I have a WD 1.3 TB hard driver, it might have some bad sectors.
I plug it in the Raspberry Pi and partition the disk with following commands

```
sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdb, then g, n, w
```

to create the new partition.
I got feedback as follows

```
The partition table has been altered.
Calling ioctl() to re-read partition table.
Syncing disks.
```

I want to use fsck to inspect the hard disk with

```
sudo fsck -p -C -a /dev/sdb1
```

The following message was received

```
fsck from util-linux 2.36.1
fsck.ext2: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdb1
/dev/sdb1:
The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>
```

Neither of the suggestion on running e2fsck is working with the same feedback above.

Please kindly suggest how to proceed.
Thanks.

Comment: Is the filesystem on `/dev/sdb1` actually `ext`? Add the output of `lsblk -f` to the question using the edit button. Do not post it in the comments.

Comment: After creating a partition with `fdisk`, you should have initialized it with `mkfs` (usually suffixed with the type of desired filesystem, e.g. `mkfs.ext4`). If you did not do that, the error from `fsck` is normal and expected.

Comment: The output of `mkfs /dev/sdb1` should also be included in the text of the question. And, as others have pointed out, `fsck` does not scan the hardware for bad blocks, you will need a different tool for that.

Answer (score 1):

e2fsck is a tool not for checking the fitness of a hard drive, but for checking the data integrity of an ext file-system. Since the partition is created from scratch, there is no file-system to check.

If you want to check the fitness of the drive, I recommend doing so by examining the drive's SMART values using `gsmartmontools`. It has a nice UI. Let it run a a conveyance or an extended test to check the disk surface for errors. If there is an error, throw the drive away. In my experience, saving the money for a new drive usually is not worth losing a terabyte of data.

Comment: To add to this, it isn't possible to repair a failing hard drive. All that a utility can do is to find bad sectors and tell the OS not to write to them. That's the case regardless of the file system.